# Go back to path from show view based on render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

This is confusing me so much,
I have 2 models `client has_many :invocies` and `invoice belongs_to client`, 
I have my `root` set up to index all `invoices` and `invoices` can also be accessed through the `clients show` View. I have a back button in my `invoice show view` that links back to the `client:id` that the `invoice` belongs to

Back link form invoices/show

```
<%= link_to 'Back', client_path(@invoice.client), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

This works fine but its really awkward to launch `invoice show` from the root path and then click `back` and be re-directed to the `client show` view. Is there a way to go back to the `root_path` or show  2 buttons in an if statement and show one depending on how a user launched the `invoice show view` in the first place? Completely stuck.

Here is my routes file

```
resources :invoices, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :index]
 resources :clients do
   resources :invoices, shallow: true
end

root 'invoices#index'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple backlink:

```
link_to 'Back', :back, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

should do in this case. It will use the `HTTP_REFERER` or a Javascript function to get to the previous page. See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more info.

**Update:**

I you need some exceptions to the "simple back link" rule, you must create a custom solution. One such solution might be that you use `link_to :back` by default **but override it by accepting a custom "back_path" parameter in special cases**. You can create a custom helper to do that.

The following example uses the standard back link by default but allows the previous page to set a `back_path` parameter that will be understood by the `back_link` helper.

```
# application_helper.rb
def back_link(params, name: "Back", class: "btn btn-primary")
  if params[:back_path].present?
    link_to name, params[:back_path], class: class 
  else
    link_to name, :back, class: class 
  ens
end
```

Now you use the link normally in your views:

```
<%= back_link(params) %>
```

And when you want to override the default behavior, simply pass the `back_path` param. You will pass this parameter typically at the page that you want to return to. Then you'll have to **pass this parameter on through all further pages and/or redirects**.

Say, for a non-trivial example, that from the client `show` page you can click a link to create a new invoice and then be redirected to the invoice `show` page and from there you want to click the back link and get to the client `show` page again.

So, add a link to the clients show page, with the `back_path` param pointing back to this page:

```
# views/clients/show.html.erb
<%= link_to 'New invoice', new_invoice_path(@client, back_path: client_path(@client)) %>
```

In the `new` page form, you'll have to add a `hidden_tag`to pass on the `back_path` param:

```
# views/invoices/_form.html.erb
<%= hidden_field_tag 'back_path', params[:back_path] %>
```

Next, in the controller's `create` action, you will also have to pass this param upon redirect:

```
# controllers/invoices_controller.rb
redirect_to invoice_url(@invoice, back_path: params[:back_path])
```

And finally, you can now use the `back_link` helper to display the correct link:

```
# views/invoices/show.html.erb
<%= back_link(params) %>
```

I know it's ugly but that's the way it is... Moreover it's not an ideal solution as typically you want a hierarchy of back links as you browse the pages (and come to a page from different paths) and this solution solves only the first back link. But I think it's something to build upon.

Comment: This is ok except when a new invoice is created I am redirecting to `show` so linking back from there takes you back to the `new invoice form`